# What is the most accurate general form of an interval estimate of a population mean, for known population variance (sigma)?

Tags: confidence-interval

I see some textbook use $\bar x \pm z_{α/2}  σ/√n $; but I think this is for infinite population or the population can be viewed as infinite. 
When the population is finite or can be viewed as finite, then a correction factor should be added before $ σ/√n $, the formula should be $\bar x ̅\pm z_{α/2}  \sqrt{(N-n)/(N-1)}\,  σ/√n $ .

More generally, it should be $ \bar x \pm z_{α/2}  σ_{\bar x}  $ .

Am I right? I want to confirm since I seldom see the correction factor. Thank you.

Comment: I made some edits to improve legibility of math notation. Please check that I did not change your meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you have the right idea. However, the finite population correction is not generally used unless sampling is without replacement and sample size $n$ is more than 10% of the population size $N.$

For example, if $N = 10,000$ and $n = 80,$ then $\sqrt{\frac{N-n}{N-1}}=0.996 \approx 1.$

*Note:* Moreover, for small $n$ and normal data, the
sample standard deviation $S$ is already a [noticeable underestimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) of infinite population standard deviation $\sigma.$ 
Precisely, $E(S) = \sigma\sqrt{\frac{2}{n-1}}\,\Gamma(\frac{n}{2})/\Gamma(\frac{n-1}{2}).$  Computation and simulation using R.

```
sqrt((10^4 - 80)/(10^4 - 1))
[1] 0.9960418

s = replicate(10^6, sd(rnorm(20, 0, 1)))
mean(s)
[1] 0.9869923  # aprx 0.98693
n = 20; sqrt(2/(n-1))*gamma(n/2)/gamma((n-1)/2)
[1] 0.9869343  # exact
n = 5;  sqrt(2/(n-1))*gamma(n/2)/gamma((n-1)/2)
[1] 0.9399856  # downward bias worse for very small n
```